# Responsive design not working for text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive design for my page, I have made the layout and it is working perfecty on resizing but when I add text in my page and then resize it, things get mess up. It is because the layout is resizing itself accordingly but the text is not resizing itself. How it will be solved?

Here is the html code:

```
<body>

<div id="mainpage">

<div id="menu">
<div id="menuhomepage"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="menublog"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="menuphoto"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="menuabout"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="menulinks"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="menucontact"><a href="#"></a></div>
</div>

<div id="header">
<div id="headertext"><a href="#">logologo</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">

<div id="articles"></div>

<div id="sidebar">
<div id="searchbar"></div>
<div id="tempus"></div>
<div id="categories"></div>
<div id="blogroll"></div>
<div id="archieve"></div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

And here goes the CSS code:

```
body
{
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #DBE2D0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
}

#mainpage
{
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 900px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

#menuhomepage
{
    background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 30%;
    height: 60px;
    float:left;
}

#menuhomepage a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: White;
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menublog
{
    background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.1%;
    float: left;
}

#menuphoto
{
    background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 15%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.1%;
    float: left;
}

#menuabout
{   background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.1%;
    float: left;
}

#menulinks
{   
    background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.1%;
    float: left;
}

#menucontact
{
    background-color: #5D7144;
    width: 24.5%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.1%;
    float: left;
}

#header
{
    height: 170px;
}

#header a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: White;
}

#headertext
{
    padding-left: 40%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

#content
{
    background-color: White;
    min-height: 1600px;
}

#articles
{
    width: 60%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 1400px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar
{
    width: 25%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 1400px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#searchbar
{
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#tempus
{
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#categories
{
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#blogroll
{
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#archieve
{
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid Gray;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#footer
{
    background-image: url(images/footer.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Check the jsfiddle code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2NNNy/

On adding the "logologo" text and resizing, the font-size is not resizing, why?

Comment: fiddle link not included.

Comment: What makes you think that it should resize with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, hope this helps

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { /* for screen size less or equal to 320px*/
     #header a{
        font-size: 80%; /*Changes as per your requirement*/
     }    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { /* for screen size less or equal to 700px*/
#header a{
    font-size: 120%; /*Changes as per your requirement*/
} 
}
```

and include this in your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I wrote this in my CSS file but what to write in my HTML file to link this CSS style to it?

Answer (score 2):

Liquid layouts alone just done cut it anymore...

You are going to want to delve into mediaqueries to get the effect you want.

Heres some good examples. Have a look at the source!

http://mediaqueri.es/

Also you might want to try this developer guide...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
   font-size: 75%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) { 
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was searching them.

Answer (score 0):

> Always use percentage for font-size and dont forget to add the
>   viewport meta in your page head

Suppose your body font-size is 100%, the default font-size will be 16px, and if you want to apply a 13px for a paragraph you can easily calculate like this

13/16 ie 81%, pretty simple huh,

happy coding :)

Comment: But that will not solve my problem since the default font-size will always be 16px and thus my text will show it up accordingly while I want to resize it on resizing the browser.

Comment: Okay, you have given a fixed 40pt, make it in percentage and apply different font-size for different mediaquery break-points

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do but I am unable to understand media query syntax. I know about the breakpoints but I don't know how to link HTMl and CSS for media query. Can you tell me what to write exactly in HTML file and CSS file.