# Resize wrapper with CSS on Responsive Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to figure out a way to expand my wrappers when I resize my browser. They are cutting off my text.

Link Here: http://kizukatech.com/bpcstest/plugintest.html

**They look great here:** [image]

**But as I resize down it starts to cut off my text and images:**
[image]

And Even More:

[image]

I have rattled my brain in every way and cannot seem to think out side the box on this problem.

Comment: The problem as I see it is quite simple : your containers are responsive but your contents are not! Your issue is directly linked to the font-size in responsive design, so I suggest you to read these posts: [Responsive design not working for text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988684/responsive-design-not-working-for-text) and [text automatically resizes without media queries (responsive design)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917578/text-automatically-resizes-without-media-queries-responsive-design)

Comment: I dont want the text to shrink I want the box to get bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the boxes to get larger you could use min-height instead of setting a specific height for the text boxes. This will cause you other problems though, as the boxes heights will vary with the amount of content.

Another option will be to set the box heights using media queries for each break point.

Comment: Dude minimum height! You're a genius! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Take off your fixed height on the boxes!

Comment: I tried this but it is applying the CSS to the element style from somewhere and I am not sure where.